# Android: Change the background color of a ClickableSpan when clicked

Tags: android

I have a SpannableString with a ClickableSpan as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            final SpannableString span = new SpannableString(items.get(i));
            final int index=i;

            span.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {

                }

                @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                    ds.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    ds.setUnderlineText(false);

                }
            }, 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            builder.append(span);
        }

//my text view
txt.setText(builder);
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

what I want to do is to change the foreground color of the span when clicked.

how can I do this ?

Comment: ds.setColor(Color.LTGRAY); does this not color for clicable span

Comment: this gives it an initial color, I want to set a different color when it's clicked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I extended the clickableSpan class and passed it a flag that lets me know that I should highlight it.

```
SpannableStringBuilder tag;
.... tag.setSpan(new WordSpan(i, tokens[i], wordtohighlitedID) {
```

.....

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;

public class WordSpan extends ClickableSpan 
{

    private int id;
    private TextPaint textpaint;
    public boolean shouldHilightWord = false;
    public WordSpan(int anID, String txt, int selected) {
        id =anID;
        // if the word selected is the same as the ID set the highlight flag
        if(selected == id)  {
            shouldHilightWord = true;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        textpaint = ds;
        ds.setColor(ds.linkColor);
        if(shouldHilightWord){
            textpaint.bgColor = Color.GRAY;         
            textpaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

        }
        //Remove default underline associated with spans
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);

    }

    public void changeSpanBgColor(View widget){
        shouldHilightWord = true;
        updateDrawState(textpaint);
        widget.invalidate();


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /**
     * This function sets the span to record the word number, as the span ID
     * @param spanID
     */
    public void setSpanTextID(int spanID){
        id = spanID;
    }

    /**
     * Return the wordId of this span
     * @return id
     */
    public int getSpanTextID(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41):

If you're looking to get rid of the green highlight on selection, this is what you want to know:

Apparently, overriding `public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)` in your custom class would not affect the highlight color. It is only used for setting the underline color (or hiding/showing it).

All you need to do is:
`textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`
where textView is what contains the ClickableSpan.

Hope it works for all of you.
Feel free to ask any related question.

Comment: exactly I was looking for this.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you want to clear textview highlight by xml, you must set android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF". For some reasons android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/transparent" ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to inherit ClickableSpan and store the color in it, then call invalidate so that changes take effect, NOTE that this is not expensive operation since we are not resetting the spannable text again instead we are just updating the already added spans, read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) and [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/underspanding-spans-1b91008b97e4) for more info ->

```
    class MutableClickableSpan(
        private val clickHandler: (MutableClickableSpan, String) -> Unit,
        private val id: String = ""
    ) : ClickableSpan() {
        private var color = 0 // we store the color in the span itself
        private var isUnderlineText = true

        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            clickHandler.invoke(this, id)
        }

        // this method gets called when we call invalidate.
        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            ds.color = color
            ds.isUnderlineText = isUnderlineText
        }

        // convenient method to update span color.
        fun update(color: Int, isUnderlineText: Boolean) {
            this.color = color
            this.isUnderlineText = isUnderlineText
        }
    }

    private fun myTest() {
        val clickHandler = { mutableClickableSpan: MutableClickableSpan, id: String ->
            mutableClickableSpan.update(Color.RED, false)
            binding.textView.invalidate() // this causes the span to get updated
            // you can also update all spans colors doing this:
            // val spannableText = binding.textView.text as Spannable
            // spannableText.getSpans<MutableClickableSpan>().forEach { it.color = Color.RED }

            // you can use the id to identify which span was clicked
        }

        val spannableText = buildSpannedString {
            append("you can click on this text, also you can click on this text")
            setSpan(MutableClickableSpan(clickHandler), 17, 21, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            setSpan(MutableClickableSpan(clickHandler), 50, 54, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        }

        binding.textView.text = spannableText
        binding.textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
view.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: This only works for ListViews, and has nothing to do with Spans.