# how to change colour of clickable textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to change the default colour of link (textview).

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("By continuing,I agree to HCP User Agreement and Terms of Services ");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(UserRegister.this, ForgotPassword.class));
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 48, 65, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.termsAndConditions);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: `ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),48,65,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)`

Comment: I have code in which they use wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); but then where should i pass clickablespan object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851655/android-change-the-background-color-of-a-clickablespan-when-clicked

Comment: @Raghunandan then where should i pass the object of  ClickableSpan

Comment: @Loren http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908547/create-clickable-link-in-text-view-in-android.

Comment: @Raghunandan THanks dude..!!!!! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the textcolor of the entire `TextView` just call `textView.setTextColor(R.color.text_color)`.

If you want to colorize only parts of the `TextView`´s text:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder("your-string");
final int start = 0, end = textView.getText().length(); // Change to the start/end of the part to colorize

// Apply some text-color
stringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources()
     .getColor(R.color.text_color)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

// Apply changes to TextView
textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

**Note**: Use String-Resources, do not pass a raw string (`"By continuing,I agree to HCP User Agreement and Terms of Services "` --> change to something like `getString(R.string.accept_user_agreement)`)